# Hash passwords before transmitting? (web)

Tags: passwords

I was reading this [Ars article](http://arstechnica.com/security/news/2010/06/content-providers-phishing-for-demographic-data-via-logins.ars) on password security and it mentioned there are sites that "hash the password before transmitting"?

Now, assuming this isn't using an SSL connection (HTTPS), a. is this actually secure and b. if it is how would you do this in a secure manor?

Edit 1: (some thoughts based on first few answers)

c. If you do hash the password before transmission, how do you use that if you only store a salted hash version of the password in your user credentials databas?

d. Just to check, if you are using a HTTPS secured connection, is any of this necessary?

Comment: If you're using HTTPS, send the password as typed in.  There are still potential vulnerabilities, but far less than not using SSL, and offhand I can't think of a vulnerability SSL has that this scheme doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only secure if the server sends a non-reusable salt (and, of course, if you use a secure hash).

Otherwise, the attacker can simply sniff the users hash, then replay the hash to log in as the user.

Note that the login is vulnerable to a man-in-the middle attack.

Comment: +1 Absolutely, if the hacker can simply re-post the hash to the server it's no more secure than a plaintext password.

Comment: @Paolo: At least the attacker cannot use the password on other sites.

Comment: So would this be a viable implementation (assuming javascript enabled): when the user submits, do an ajax call with a unique id for the request, server responds with non-reusable salt based on id, client browser uses SHA-1 (or better) to hash salt and password, and then transmit that to server which checks password, ajax id, username?

Comment: nevermind, that wouldn't work, I just read Thorarin post and comments and realized double hashing would be a problem. If you securely store as a salted hashed in your database, you wouldn't be able to use it with the ajax salt/hash unless you use some kind of decryptable hash.

Comment: @wag: Actually, it would work.  There's nothing wrong with double-hashing.  You can send both the (fixed) salt for the hash in the database and the (random) non-resuable salt, then hash the password on the client using the fixed salt, and hash the resulting hash using the random salt.

Comment: PS: A decryptable hash is called an encryption.

Comment: @Slaks, +1 for encryption (couldn't think of the word before), but as far as sending the database hash, I thought that should be kept as secret as possible (probably never used outside of the server)

Comment: @wag: I don't mean to send the database hash.  I mean to send the database salt, so that the client can create the database hash by itself.

Comment: @Slaks, yeah thats what I meant, shouldn't the database salt be kept secret too? i currently use a double hash implementation for my database hashes, a unique string for each user plus a standard salt for the application that is kept secret. I read on an other StackOverflow question that the application salt should be kept secret.

Comment: @wag: There's nothing wrong with exposing the salt. 
  Note that the salt should not be limited to ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it secure, but it's better than nothing. If you let the server pick a hash salt every time a user logs in, that will protects against replay. However, there's nothing protecting users from man in the middle attacks while they are logged in.

You will have to store the salt you generated somewhere on the server while the user is logging in. If that is a problem, you could hash the salt with another (fixed) salt, use the result as a checksum and add both to your login form as hidden fields.

There are some [JavaScript SHA-1 implementations](http://www.webtoolkit.info/demo/javascript-sha-1) around that should do the trick. Don't use MD5 if you can help it.

Comment: +1 -- but it's not much better than nothing if you care about security at all.

Comment: @tvanfosson: one problem is that you end up having to store passwords in plain text, or use some kind of double hashing. The latter makes it rather complicated, with limited benefits.

Comment: I'd be more concerned that Mallory would have generated a rainbow table based on the salt she's passing to Bob (or, since she's smart, several rainbow tables and  with different salts) and will eventualy triangulate Bob's real password so she can use it in the future to talk with Alice.

Comment: @tvanfosson: that is a concern, yes. Each new hash makes it more likely someone will be able to find the original password. If they tried hard enough :)

Answer (score 1):

You can protect this scheme against man-in-the-middle attacks by using the salted database hash to generate a secret key for symmetric encryption.

It would work like this:

- Server looks up the password hash in the database *H<sub>D</sub>* along with salt *S<sub>D</sub>*
- Server chooses a random salt *S<sub>R</sub>*
- Server generates a secret key *K* by hashing the database hash with *S<sub>R</sub>*
- Server sends *S<sub>D</sub>* and *S<sub>R</sub>* to the client

---

- Client calculates *H<sub>D</sub>* by hashing the user's password with *S<sub>D</sub>*
- Client calculates *K* by hashing *H<sub>D</sub>* with *S<sub>P</sub>*
- Client encrypts all server communication with *K*

This scheme creates a random session key *K* based on the user's password.
A man in the middle would not be able to derive *K* without knowing the user's password (or *H<sub>D</sub>*, which must be kept secret), and therefore cannot impersonate the server.